# Entering list's values from keyboard: <__main__.ListNode> error

Tags: python

I'm writing a python program to merge two sorted lists. However when running this program, while trying to enter their values from the keyboard, it produces the error:

```
<__main__.ListNode object at 0x000002D68AD6FFD0>
```

The program is:

```
class ListNode(object):
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None

class MergeTwoLists(object):
    def mergeTwoLists(self,l1,l2):
        if not l1 or not l2:
            return l1 or l2
        if l1.val < l2.val:
            l1.next = self.mergeTwoLists(l1.next,l2)
            return l1
        else:
            l2.next = self.mergeTwoLists(l1,l2.next)
            return l2

#input the two integer lists
list1 = []
for i in range(0,6):
    list1.append(input("enter a integer of list1:"))
head = ListNode(list1[0])
p = head
for j in list1[1:]:
    node = ListNode(j)
    p.next = node
    p = p.next
l1 = head

list2 = []
for i in range(0,6):
    list2.append(input("enter an integer of list2:"))
head = ListNode(list2[0])
p = head
for j in list2[1:]:
    node = ListNode(j)
    p.next = node
    p = p.next
l2 = head

list_result = MergeTwoLists().mergeTwoLists(l1,l2)
print("the list result:")
print(list_result)
```

Could someone please help me with this problem?

Comment: That's not an error.  It's the default way of printing an object.  Your code has a lot more problems than that, though.

Comment: could you please tell me the problem in this program, your correction is very important for me

Comment: It's because your `ListNode` class has neither a `__str__` nor `__repr__` method, so `print()` doesn't know how to what to do so it defaults to what you're seeing (which technically isn't an error, it has nothing to do with entering values from the keyboard...it just happens to not be what you apparently want).

Comment: Then what I should to print the value of the ListNode, how to write the code

Comment: Look up  __str__ in the docs. https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=__str__#str  It should return a string that represents the list as you want it to be printed.  You can write it recursively.